# Django POST save and delete

Tags: django, post, django-models, onclick, delete-row

I'm attempting to save records into a model using the modelform (*this part is working as intended*) and delete records from the same model using a checkbox (*can't figure this piece out*). I am creating a comprehensive view so I'm not creating using a def variable(reqeust, id) function and my intention is to have both POST methods redirect back to the same page. How would I go about deleting a model record using a checkbox and POST? I will add an `@login_required` decorator later. Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class ReportDirectory(models.Model):
    report_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, blank=False)
    report_desc = models.TextField()
    report_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    report_loc = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=300)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    main_tags = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    # Renames the item in the admin folder

    def __str__(self):
        return self.report_name

   
class Favorite(models.Model):
    directory_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_report = models.ForeignKey(ReportDirectory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorited = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.directory_user)+" - "+str(self.user_report)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views import generic
from .models import ReportDirectory, Favorite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import FavoriteForm


def report_directory(request):
    favorite = Favorite.objects.filter(directory_user=request.user.id, favorited=True)
    reports = ReportDirectory.objects.exclude(favorite__directory_user=request.user.id, favorite__favorited=True)
    
    favform = FavoriteForm(initial={'directory_user':request.user,},)
    
    context = {
        'reports':reports,
        'favorite':favorite,
        'favform':favform
    }

    if request.method =='POST' and 'favorited' in request.POST:
        form = FavoriteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/report_directory')
        else:
            form = FavoriteForm()
    elif request.method =='POST' and 'deletefav' in request.POST:
        Favorite.objects.filter(id=id).delete()        
        return redirect('/report_directory')

    return render(request, 'counter/report_directory.html',context)
```

Comment: 'deletefav' is the name of your checkbox tag? What result do you see now?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm not seeing anything now. The page simply redirects without impacting the model record. Here is a snippet of the HTML: 
<form method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <input id={{ favorite.id }} type="checkbox" name="deletefav" class="gls-checkbox" onclick="submit()" checked>
</form>